# How do I use a comma-separated list of values with SQL IN clause

Tags: c#, sql

I want to apply the SQL `IN` clause in my query for a names column. I know there is an option `'like'` but, in the UI the user selects the names of customer from a multi-select dropdown, so I have a comma-separated list of names like 'rocky,joni,david' and to use SQL `IN` the list needs to be like 'rocky','joni','david'. Let me know if something is not clear in my question.

Comment: Never store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lot of trouble. One item per row!

Comment: Is it always three values?  Can it be more?  Can it be 100 or 1000?  It sounds like you're trying to generate dynamic SQL, which has some pitfalls you should understand.  There may be better ways to handle it, depending on my questions above.

Comment: show us the query so we can help out we don't know what you did.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got one product specific answer, and it's not really fair to waste peoples' time writing answers for wrong product...)

Comment: sry @nvoigt I didn't mentioned what i have tried because its a log story ;)

Comment: you got it bro @Hambone but I have to handle it the way it is, client wants this, yes its dynamic sql query :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MS SQL Server, you can use a split function such as the following one found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/3854195

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

Then you can use `IN` since the function returns your values as a table.

```
DECLARE @CustomerList varchar(max)

/* Populate @CustomerList with your comma separated values  */

SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName IN (
        SELECT [Name]
        FROM dbo.splitstring(@CustomerList)
        )
```

Comment: It would be good to add a reference copy of the script in case the link ever goes down (Questions and answers can get deleted after all). Be sure to still include a link to the source.

Comment: Edited.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I would tweak that last code example you copied from the original post to actully use the `splitstring` function in a `IN`, other than that, good job!

Comment: Please specify which dbms this is for. (No product tagged in question.)

Comment: Edited to specify the dbms and show an applicable code example.

Comment: you did before  me it I was almost there,

Comment: `ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
       
        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        
    END 
    RETURN 
END`

Comment: @RKSharma I am glad that I could help.  There were a lot of questions like which DBMS because it is usually one of the tags so we know which "flavor" of SQL we are dealing with.  I think I automatically thought MS because of C#.  :)